C# Animations with fade out,in etc
Im trying to find a way to create this type of animations in c# winforms or any type of c#. But everything that i could find was this Code Project page, and i couldent use any of it, what im trying to do is this: Streamable URL Video
I made that design in figma and converted it into c# winforms, but i really cant do the animations.
I tryied to use the animations from code project but they dont work as expected, they are laggy and it simply breaks the image when it is resizing.

Why are you using WinForms for this instead of something more appropriate like WPF?

i dont know wpf

How to apply a fade transition effect to Images using a Timer? -> Fade in, fade out and blend. No easing functions are used there, but those functions usually just apply a calculation based on a bezier curve (to one axis), to set the interval of a timer (to alter the progression, i.e., to make the progression non-linear)
